# jQuery jscrollpane vertical with white-space:nowrap CSS prop

Tags: jquery, html, jscrollpane, css

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown__list">
  <div class="dropdown__list__w">
    <ul class="dropdown__list__box">
      <li class="dropdown__list__item"><span class="dropdown__list__val">Item text</span></li>
      ...
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.dropdown__list__item {
  height: 19px;
  line-height: 19px;
  overflow: hidden;
  ..
}
  .dropdown__list__val {
    display: block;
    height: 19px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    ...
  }
```

I'm using .jScrollPane() on .dropdown__list__w which has fixed height. With white-space:nowrap I get bad results as you can see [here](http://name-k.com/screenshots/140814121312_kiss_25kb.jpg). When I remove it, everything goes as [it should be](http://name-k.com/screenshots/140814127764_kiss_24kb.jpg).

I can't remove white-space:nowrap because text-overflow:ellipsis will not work without it. So, how can I make jScrollPane work properly or use text-overflow:ellipsis without white-space:nowrap?

Comment: Can you make a demo in JSFiddle to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

You could make the element *fixed width* and remove white-space:nowrap

Comment: In this case, text-overflow will not work as it should.